# Tcolorbox: Margin between upper and lower part

Tags: tcolorbox

Which option controls the vertical spacing between upper and lower part inside the box?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
    \tcblower
    This is the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 11 of the tcolorbox documentation has a useful overview of the lengths:

[image]

This means you want to change the `middle` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[middle=10pt]
    This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
    \tcblower
    This is the lower part of the box.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did check the manual, but I was searching for the wrong term.